# How to get correct yaw from a rolled Gyroscope

Tags: gyroscopes

I have used an smartphone to get three dimentional gyroscope values. Their units are radians per second.

I used integral of Z to measure the yaw. But it only works correctly when my smartphone is horizontal. Having the phone in my hands, When I roll it about 45 degrees and rotate myself for 90 degrees, the yaw rotates less than that.

How can I fix the yaw by having the amount of Roll of the smartphone?

Comment: How do you define "yaw"? On my tables to seems to do exactly what I would expect it to do. The phone doesn't measure your yaw, it measures its yaw, and if the two of you don't have the same orientation, then you can't expect it to know what coordinate system you are in.

Comment: @CuriousOne I think he was essentially just asking how to convert between the two sets of coordinates.

Comment: @DuncanHarris: I thought so, too, that's why I was asking for how he wants to define "yaw". I do agree, by the way, that it's not a completely trivial problem. Euler angles and the transformations have always given me trouble with my intuition. To this day I am struggling with 3d design tools when it comes to rotating "stuff". :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this would hold for a perfect gyroscope:

(integral of Z) = (correct yaw) * cos(roll)

Your smartphone gyroscope might respond differently.  The only foolproof method would be to take data for known yaws at each of a variety of rolls, and then fit a model to the data.

Comment: As the result of cosine is less than 1, the yaw would become less than it is. But I want it to become more.

Comment: you are solving for the correct yaw...